# Query gives correct answer on second run

Tags: mysql

I have the query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT sort.*,
    (
        CASE concat(question_id,`type`)
        WHEN
            @curType 
        THEN
            @curRow := coalesce(@curRow,0) + 1
        ELSE
            @curRow := 1 AND @curType := concat(question_id,`type`)
        END
    ) + 1 AS rank
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT a.* FROM
        ul_attempt_responses a
        LEFT JOIN us_attempts b ON a.attempt_id = b.id
        WHERE b.user_id = 3
        AND response IS NOT NULL
        AND trim(response) != ''
        AND b.authenticated = 1
        ORDER BY question_id, type, id DESC
    ) sort
) final WHERE rank = 2;
```

On my local machine, when the query is executed twice, that is when I get the correct response. But on the Production Server, it works on the first time.

What could be the problem? Is there a problem with the query.

Comment: What happens on the first execution? Should we try and guess?

Comment: Question: How many rows are supposed to come back, 1 row whose rank is 2 or are you looking for rank 2 for every type ?

Comment: rank 2 for every type.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? For newer version, you can use `WINDOW` functions

Answer (score 1):

There's so much wrong with your query.

In your subquery `sort` you do a `left join`, but your `where` clause actually converts it to an `inner join`.

You seem to rely on the `order by` in the `sort` subquery. You don't do an `order by` in the outer query. Maybe you can practically rely on it to work, but in theory you can not.

Your variables `@curType` and `@curRow` are nowhere initialized. Either do this before the query with a `SET @variable = 'whatever'` command or in a cross joined subquery in your query. This is most likely the cause, why it gives a "correct answer" on the second run. Variables have session scope! Not query scope. You can not rely on them to be `NULL` or whatever you want them to be when you don't initialize them.

The keyword `AND` is not used to do two commands! It's used in **boolean expressions**, which return either `1` (true) or `0` (false) or `NULL` (unknown, if one of the operands is `NULL`. So, better check your result, if it really is correct ;)

Since it's not totally clear to me, what you're trying to do, I can only have a guess. But something like this may be what you're looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.*,
    @curRow := IF(concat(question_id,`type`) = @curType, @curRow + 1, 1) AS rank,
    @curType := concat(question_id,`type`)
    FROM
    ul_attempt_responses a
    INNER JOIN us_attempts b ON a.attempt_id = b.id
    JOIN (SELECT @curType := NULL, @curRow := 0) var_init_subquery
    WHERE b.user_id = 3
    AND response IS NOT NULL
    AND trim(response) != ''
    AND b.authenticated = 1
    ORDER BY question_id, type, id DESC
) final WHERE rank = 2;
```

Comment: Can you please make the edits, and pass me the query for me to see, what you mean exactly. Also I can not set the variables in start, because I need to plug in the query into another application!

Comment: @user57391 Edited my answer.

Comment: Nope, the query you answered, doesnt give the required/desired result. The mysql query that I commented does, however, on the second run. Is ther anything else that you do to my query, so that I get the results on the first run?

Comment: Well, like I said, I can only guess. Come up with the requirements, maybe sample data and desired result and we can help. But not with this little information.